Call commonModalDialogClose Server Side
I have a method that opens a modal window. This method includes a callback function that checks whether the form is in display mode or edit mode. If it is in edit mode, it attaches the resultVal to the item without refreshing the page. If it's in display mode, it refreshes the page since the resultVal has been saved directly on the item server-side. Within the modal window, when the user clicks 'Send', the SendEmail method is invoked. This method verifies if an email has been successfully sent. When successful, it currently sends the response as a script to close the modal window via commonModalCloseDialog(result, resultVal), where the resultVal is the input from the user and is used in the callback.
I'm wondering if there is a better approach, given that my current approach is susceptible to cross-site scripting.
Method that opens modal and defines the callback:
function dialogfunction(pageUrl, formType) {
    //Open dialog with call back for modifying body text (on EditForm)
    var options =
        {
            url: pageUrl,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            args: formType,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: function (dialogResult, returnValue) {
                if (dialogResult == 1) {  //Check for OK from dialog

                    //If EditForm - append the message to the text instead of trying to store it directly on the list item
                    //(Storing it directly on the listitem will lead to a save conflict)
                    if (formType == 'Edit' && returnValue.saveMessage) {
                        var tbBody = ccm$("div[role='textbox'][id^='" + textBodyIdPrefix + "']");

                        if (tbBody && tbBody.length > 0) {// Location: /Lists/Tasks
                            //prepend message to existing html
                            tbBody.html(returnValue.message + tbBody.html());
                        } else {// Location: /Lists/Issues/
                            tbBody = ccm$("div[role='textbox'][id^='" + issueTextBodyIdPrefix + "']");
                            if (tbBody && tbBody.length > 0) {
                                //prepend message to existing html
                                tbBody.html(returnValue.message + tbBody.html());
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(formType == 'Edit' && returnValue.responsible)
                    {
                        ccmSetFieldValue("Responsible", "AssignedTo","SPFieldUser", returnValue.responsible);

                    }
                    
                    //If display do a refresh so the new entry can be seen
                    if (formType == 'Display' && returnValue.saveMessage) {
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(dialogResult);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}

How the response is sent server-side:
if (success)
{
   response = $"<script type='text/javascript'>var parameters = {jsParameterString};window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, parameters);</script>";
}
else
{
   response = LoadResource(ResourceName.Notify_SendError, web);
}

Response.Write(response);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();

